# Can't get value from radio button

Tags: php, html

I want to get the data from radio button when I submit it, but
I don't know why I can't get the value from radio it.

My code

```
<?php
   $choice = $_GET['choice'];
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <table align="center">
        <tr><td>Please select</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="0">aaaa</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="1">bbbb</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="2">cccc</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="3">dddd</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
             <?php echo"$choice";?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$_POST` Instead of `$_GET`  to get data from form. Or you can  use `$_REQUEST` also.Replace `$_GET['choice']` with `$_POST['choice']` or `$_REQUEST['choice'].`

Comment: Don't. Ever. Use. `$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$_GET`, but the form is **posted**. Use `$choice = $_POST['choice']`.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is `POST` but you're looking for it in `$_GET[]`.  Look for it in `$_POST['choice']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `method` of your form element should match the variable you access for the form data:

```
<form method="post">
// Need to use the $_POST[] array  to access values

<form method="get">
// Use the $_GET[] array to access values
```

$_GET is typically used for url strings.  Usually you will want the method of your form to be `post`.

Answer (score 0):

If your form has attribute method set to POST, than you should use _POST global array like this - `<?php $choice = $_POST['choice']; ?>`