# Radio button value getting undefined in text box

Tags: php, radio-button

I am try to store the radio button value in another page using pop up window and function
but when I am submitting radio value I'm getting undefined error in text fields.

```
 <script langauge="javascript">
 function post_value() {
     opener.document.f1.OPRID.value = document.frm.OPRID.value;
     self.close();
 }
 <input type="radio" name="OPRID" id="radio" value=<?=$objResult["OPRID"];?>>
 <input type="button" value='Submit' onclick="post_value();">
```

and other page text fields

```
 <form method="post" action='' name='f1'>
 <table border=0  width=550> <tr>
 <td>Your Name</font><input id="OPRID" name="OPRID" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST 
  ['OPRID']) ? $_POST['OPRID'] : ""); ?>"/> 
   <a href="javascript:void(0);"
  NAME="My Window Name" title=" My title here "
    onClick=window.open       

 ("popwindow.php","Ratting","width=650,height=550,0,status=0,scrollbars=1");>
 Click here to open the child window</a> 

   </td></tr> </table></form>
```

but in text fields i have getting undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

For check boxes, php passing value if only check box selected. so you can check is that check box received to PHP page. if its received user has selected it or if user not selected, no check box name passing to PHP page.

so you can check

if(isset($_POST["chk"]))

... if this returns true, that means user selected check box and if not user not selected...

Comment: Found this post..
check it here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505936/cant-get-value-from-radio-button

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes only pass something if they are checked. Either you check with isset if they are set or you add a hidden field before the checkbox with the same name and a default value (which will get overwritten by the checkbox if it is checked).

Comment: i am using radio button

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see where have you used radio button. If everything is right with it, try printing all post data on the other page to get an idea if the control's value is getting passed.
print_r($_POST)
you should see the radio control name as key to POST array.
Say on first page you have <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="this is value"/>

then result of print_r($_POST) should be Array=>("radio1"=>"this is value")

access its value as $_POST["radio1"]

Comment: sorry but not help full

Comment: question seems unclear. What exactly you want to perform? Seems you accessing a form of 1 page from another page which is not possible.

Comment: tell me what you want to perform; so that can understand it and help you. Above description is too less. if there are two different pages you working then name them. Paste content of both the pages.
Page1
<content>

Page2
<content>

and what you want from page one to display on page2

Comment: i hve use two pages one is popwindow.php its show code uper side and other is below where iam use text fields and

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some errors/problems:

- Remove the JavaScript, it's unnecessary.
- To submit something to another page (to use `$_POST`/`$_GET`), use a `<form>`
- Keep your code readable; try indenting and use new lines for elements

Make your code look like this:

#### Main page

```
<form method="POST" action="otherpage.php">
    <input type="radio" name="OPRID" id="radio" value="<?php echo $objResult["OPRID"];?>" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then, when the submit button is pressed, the form is submitted to otherpage.php, so `$_POST['OPRID']` has a value there:

#### otherpage.php

```
<form method="post" action="" name="f1">
    <table border=0 width=550>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Your Name
                <input id="OPRID" name="OPRID" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['OPRID']) ? $_POST['OPRID'] : ""); ?>" /> 
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" name="My Window Name" title=" My title here " onClick="window.open('popwindow.php','Ratting','width=650,height=550,0,status=0,scrollbars=1');" />
                    Click here to open the child window
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The part `value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['OPRID']) ? $_POST['OPRID'] : ""); ?>"` means:

- `value="..."` - put some text in the textbox
- `<?php ... ?>` - execute a piece of PHP code
- `echo ...` - print some text
- `(isset($_POST['OPRID']) ? $_POST['OPRID'] : "");` - if `$_POST` contains a value for `OPRID`, then (`?`) use that value, otherwise (`:`) use nothing (`""`)

Comment: ok  but Submit button not working....when i am click on Submit its not go to otherpage.php page

Comment: when i am click on "Click here to open the child window" then open window its wrok and then i am select radio button value and click sumbit ..and problm is main page is open in same window

Comment: If you want a form submitted in a new window/tab, add this to the `<form>` tag: `target="_blank"`

Comment: which fuction use for radio button in javascript

Comment: Why do you want to use a JS function for that? What does it do?

Comment: my need is when  i am click on open child window open a window box in here i am select a radio button and click on sumbit  then window box close and radio button value fill in the text filds...